# How to convert a large number to base 36 using DC or other

Tags: numbers, 64-bit, dc

I am trying to represent the maximum 64-bit unsigned value in different bases.

For base 2 (binary) it would be 64 1's:

```
    1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

For base 16 (hex) it would be 16 F's

```
    FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

For base 10 (decimal) it would be:

```
    18446744073709551615
```

I'm trying to get the representation of this value in base 36 (it uses 0-9 and A-Z).  There are many online base converters, but they all fail to produce the correct representation because they are limited by 64-bit math.

Does anyone know how to use DC (which is an extremely hard to use string math processors that can handle numbers of unlimited magnitude) and know how to do this conversion?  Either that or can anyone tell me how I can perform this conversion with a calculator that won't fail due to integer roll-over?

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraüh. What is meant with *DC*?

Comment: _DC_ is a program written in assembly prior to the invention of the C programming language.  It is short for "Desk Calculator".  Unfortunately, using it just as hard as programming in assembly because you have to load and pop the operands on and off the registers manually and all kinds of crazy stuff.  It's way over my head, but it is by far the most powerful math processor I know of.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now I found it also at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_(computer_program))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mad a quick test with ruby:

```
i = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'.to_i(16)
puts i               #18446744073709551615
puts i.to_s(36)      #3w5e11264sgsf
```

You may also use larger numbers:

```
i = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'.to_i(16) ** 16
puts i                  
puts i.to_s(36)
```

result:

```
179769313486231590617005494896502488139538923424507473845653439431848569886227202866765261632299351819569917639009010788373365912036255753178371299382143631760131695224907130882552454362167933328609537509415576609030163673758148226168953269623548572115351901405836315903312675793605327103910016259918212890625
1a1e4vngailcqaj6ud31s2kk9s94o3tyofvllrg4rx6mxa0pt2sc06ngjzleciz7lzgdt55aedc9x92w0w2gclhijdmj7le6osfi1w9gvybbfq04b6fm705brjo535po1axacun6f7013c4944wa7j0yyg93uzeknjphiegfat0ojki1g5pt5se1ylx93knpzbedn29
```

---

A short explanation what happens with big numbers:

Normal numbers are [`Fixnums`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html). If you get larger numbers, the number becomes a [`Bignum`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Bignum.html):

```
small = 'FFFFFFF'.to_i(16)
big = 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'.to_i(16) ** 16

puts "%i is a %s" % [ small, small.class ]
puts "%i\n is a %s" % [ big, big.class ]
puts "%i^2 is a %s" % [ small, (small ** 2).class ]
```

Result:

```
268435455 is a Fixnum
179769313486231590617005494896502488139538923424507473845653439431848569886227202866765261632299351819569917639009010788373365912036255753178371299382143631760131695224907130882552454362167933328609537509415576609030163673758148226168953269623548572115351901405836315903312675793605327103910016259918212890625
 is a Bignum
268435455^2 is a Bignum
```

From the [documentation of Bignum](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Bignum.html):

> Bignum objects hold integers outside the range of Fixnum. Bignum objects are created automatically when integer calculations would otherwise overflow a Fixnum. When a calculation involving Bignum objects returns a result that will fit in a Fixnum, the result is automatically converted.

Comment: Yes I think that is the correct answer.  I can't really tell, but since the hex to decimal comes out with the right value, I assume the hex to base36 is also correct.  I wonder how ruby does that!  In the 2nd example, that value would cause an integer overflow in most languages.

Comment: I added a short explanation about rubys `Bignum`.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with dc, but the output is not extremely useful.

```
$ dc
36
o
16
i
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
p
 03 32 05 14 01 01 02 06 04 28 16 28 15
```

Here's the explanation:

Entering a number by itself pushes that number

`o` pops the stack and sets the output radix.

`i` pops the stack and sets the input radix.

`p` prints the top number on the stack, in the current output radix.  However, dc prints any output with a higher radix than 16 as binary (not ASCII).

In dc, the commands may be all put on the same line, like so:

```
$ dc
36o16iFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFp
 03 32 05 14 01 01 02 06 04 28 16 28 15
```

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Get any language that can handle arbitrarily large integers. Ruby, Python, Haskell, you name it.
2. Implement the basic step: modulo 36 gives you the next digit, division by 36 gives you the number with the last digit cut out.
3. Map the digits to characters the way you like. For instance,  `'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[digit]` is fine by me. Append digits to the result as you produce them.
4. ???
5. Return the concatenated string of digits. Profit!